# tomcat realm set user roles dynamically

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, jdbcrealm

I am using tomcat security for my application:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/> 
<!--This is only applicable for Tomcat 8.5 and higher version with SQL server authentication-->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
          driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=xxxxx" connectionName="xxxx" connectionPassword="xxxx"             roleNameCol="role_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userNameCol="user_name" userRoleTable="user_roles" userTable="users">
        <CredentialHandler algorithm="MD5" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"/>
    </Realm>
</Realm>
```

Now I want to be able to dynamically set new roles to the logged-in user from within the application whatever the authentication datasource may be. I need this to be deployed in an application and the client won't let us have the authentication database details and would prefer to themselves set the realm details. So it should work for all server/database types and hence be generic to the extent as possible.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, add the corresponding records to the database?

Comment: I want to be able to set the roles dynamically (ex. through the `request` variable) for all server/database types. Is there any way to dynamically obtain database credentials used in the authentication. I understand that tomcat security does not provide option to get list of all roles assigned to the user and we have to use `request.isUserInRole` and check for each role. I need this to be deployed in an application and the client won't let us have the authentication database details and would prefer to themselves set the `realm` details.